# neo4j is taking too much time for the cypher query "MATCH (n:City{name : "hyderabad"})-[:CONTAINS]->(p:BusinessDetails) return p"

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo, neomodel

i am using neo4j community version , i am having 1 node of "City" , and approx 5000 nodes of "BusinessDetails" connected with realtion "CONTAINS" from "City" to "BusinessDetails" , when 1 am using the cypher query

```
MATCH (n:City{name : "hyderabad"})-[:CONTAINS]->(p:BusinessDetails) return p
```

it is taking approx 8 seconds to fetch the results. How to optimize this ? and why it is taking so much of time?
i am really new with neo4j.

Comment: Please confirm that your DB contains only one `City` node, as your question states. Does this query return 1: `MATCH (n:City) RETURN COUNT *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure you've added index on the City name

```
CREATE INDEX ON :City(name)
```

Next always Match the filtering in a separate match statement

```
MATCH (n:City{name : "hyderabad"})
MATCH n-[:CONTAINS]->(p:BusinessDetails)
RETURN p
```

This will enhance your performance a bit. Anyway this can be a configuration problem or hardware as you are talking about very small numbers compared to what I'm using and still I'm having better performance.